# Get RecyclerView total item count in espresso

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-espresso

I am using RecyclerView and i need to get the total count of items in the RecyclerView using android espresso. How can i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count RecyclerView items with Espresso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399787/how-to-count-recyclerview-items-with-espresso)

Answer (score 5):

I would do it like this:

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MyClass> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule(MyActivity.class);

@Test
public void myTest() {
    RecyclerView recyclerView = activityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_recyclerview)
    int itemCount = recyclerView.getAdapter().getItemCount();
}
```

Comment: Minor comment, `;` is missing in first line of myTest method, not able to edit answer

Comment: ActivityTestRule is replaced by ActivityScenarioRule. would you please comment on How to do it in ActivityScenarioRule

Answer (score 0):

While [Thekarlo95's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42275120/2286422) specifically and fully answers the question, I would like to show my example on how to use his method together with [Stéphane's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446889/2286422) to test a difference in count before and after specific action:

```
@Test
public void FilterClickShouldChangeRecyclerViewCount() {
    // Get items count before action
    RecyclerView recyclerView = mActivityTestRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    int countBefore = Objects.requireNonNull(recyclerView.getAdapter()).getItemCount();
    Log.e("count", "Items count before: " + countBefore);

    // Perform action
    ViewInteraction actionMenuItemView = onView(
            allOf(
                    withId(R.id.action_filter),
                    withContentDescription("Show Favorites")));
    actionMenuItemView.perform(click());

    // Verify that items count has changed
    onView(withId(R.id.recycler_view))
            // Instead of 'not', you can use any other hamcrest Matcher like 'is', 'lessThan' etc.
            .check(new RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(not(countBefore)));
}
```

And below is a code for `RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion` class (just put it on a separate file). Note there are two constructors available:

1. `RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(int expectedCount)` - parameter of type integer is expected, default `is` matcher is used.
2. `RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(Matcher<Integer> matcher)` - parameter of type `Matcher<Integer>` is expected, like `is(3)`, `lessThan(4)` etc.

   ```
   public class RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion implements ViewAssertion {

       private final Matcher<Integer> matcher;

       public RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(int expectedCount) {
           this.matcher = is(expectedCount);
       }

       public RecyclerViewItemCountAssertion(Matcher<Integer> matcher) {
           this.matcher = matcher;
       }

       @Override
       public void check(View view, NoMatchingViewException noViewFoundException) {
           if (noViewFoundException != null) {
               throw noViewFoundException;
           }

           RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
           RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = recyclerView.getAdapter();
           assert adapter != null;
           assertThat(adapter.getItemCount(), matcher);
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

with ActivityScenarioRule

```
@get: Rule
val activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule(ShowListActivity::class.java)
@Test
fun testItemCount(){
    activityScenarioRule.scenario.onActivity { activityScenarioRule ->
        val recyclerView = activityScenarioRule.findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.movieListRecyclerView)
        val itemCount = recyclerView.adapter?.itemCount?:0
    ....
    }
}
```