# How to check if a value exists in firebase database - android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, unique

I am new to firebase via Android(Java) and was wondering how to check if a user already exists in a database of the following format:

```
    gdb-2fbgg{

      users{


         Michael{
              age: 20
              height: 150
              name: Michael
                }


         Bob{
              age: 20
              height: 150
              name: Bob
                }
       }
}
```

For example upon a button press, I would like to check the firebase to see if the username "Michael" exists ( first level michael - not "michael" within object michael.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `.child("Michael").exists()` method or `.hasChild("Michael")` with SingleValueEvent within onDataChange

```
DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference users = root.child("users");
users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.child("Michael").exists()) {
                // run some code
            }else{

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Understand this now :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare hander with delay as per your preference in onCreate() and call a method from here

```
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ok();
            }
        },3000);
```

Then create this method body

```
public void ok(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Count is : "+adapter.getItemCount(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Now you will get count after specfied delay

Comment: i called this methods after some delay because if i call instantly in onCreate then default value will be shown which is 0