# How to check if firebase recylerview has values or it is empty in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I dont like to show empty RecyclerView to users. I know there is getItemCount method in recyclerview, but i think reyclerview is executed on separate thread maybe. Its because whenever i try to call adapter.getitemcount it gives count 0 quickly even when my recyclerview will have values coming from firebase. So i think maybe till the values come the getItemCount method is executed before and returns 0 or maybe it is executed on separate thread. But either way i get 0 even when my recyclerview has values coming from firebase. So i want to check if my firebase recycler is empty or not and then change views accordingly, becoz i dont like to show the users and empty recyclerview (an empty activity). 
plz suggest how should i check it? btw heres my simple firebase adapter code :

```
 allFriendsAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendsModel, ViewHolder>(friendsOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull FriendsModel model) {


                  }

                  @Override
                  public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                  }
              });


 if(allFriendsAdapter .getItemcount==0){ //this is always returning 0 even when my recyclerview has values

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ValueEventListener` to check if any values exists:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
Query queries = ref.orderByChild("name").equalTo(name_here);
queries.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"data exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this,"No data exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

In your Adapter, you need to use a query to be able to get the data, example as the above query and it will also check if the data exists.

Then you can configure the adapter by building `FirebaseRecyclerOptions`:

```
FirebaseRecyclerOptions<FriendsModel> friendsOptions =
        new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<FriendsModel>()
                .setQuery(queries, FriendsModel.class)
                .build();
```

Comment: Isn't onDataChange an asynchronous call??

Comment: it's the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43959582/how-to-check-if-a-value-exists-in-firebase-database-android the difference is here he is using it with firebaserecycleradapter

Comment: ahh ok i get it,you used .exists instead of fetching the data,my bad

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks for the answer , i am already using queries in my firebase recycler adapter i just didnt mention any of the confidential code here. Anyways , so what you meant to say is i should first check if that query exist ? so basically attach a listener to that query first , and then if snapshot exists , should write adapter code inside it , right ?

Comment: yes just keep it as it, but before the adapter code check if data exists using the code above, dont write the adapter code inside the listener though..

Comment: umm bro even if i write adapter code inside it , suppose if data exists , so writing inside it wouldnt be a harm right ?infact if data exist then it will populate the adapter with values. so if it doesnt exist i can show some pop up like u have no friends yet in the else condition of it . Am i going right mate ?

Comment: it does not matter because you would have `friendsOptions` as a parameter in the `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` which would call the `setQuery` and checks the `queries` variable to see if there is data or not. Anw just try the answer

Comment: yes there is a friendsOptions. Btw i didnt knew we can set listener to queries also. ( i thought its just used when performing some action for example setvalues,getvalue or remove value). Thanks for this . I will try this in few time (maybe in few hours). And will accept ur answer surely if it works. Thanks alot.

Comment: Hello @PeterHaddad your answer is working perfectly fine , i am initializing my firebase adapter in ondatachange only when datasnapshot exists, otherwise i show some other view. Thank you for your answer. I have accepted it. And sorry it took me little time ,i was little busy. Thanks again ,cheers :)

Comment: @PeterHaddad i cant , my stack points/reputation is quite less. But maybe you can upvote the question hh.

Comment: Done. @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 9):

Simply override `onDataChanged` and check for `getItemCount()` there.

Comment: In Which archive?

Comment: link to how it's done https://stackoverflow.com/a/57631222/8478944