# How to see if FirestoreRecyclerAdapter is empty?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know how is it possible to discover when `FirestoreRecyclerAdapter` is ONLY empty. With the following code, I can discover if it has one or more instances into it, but it won't tell me exactly when it has no objects inside. The verification `if(adapter.getItemCount == 0)` displays everytime because adapter passes through the 0 count everytime, so apparently this function won't work.

So how is it possible to discover if it is totally empty?

Here is my code:

```
Query query = spotsCollection.whereEqualTo("cityId", cityId).limit(5);

FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Spots> options = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Spots>()
    .setQuery(query, Spots.class)
    .build();

FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Spots, SpotViewHolder> adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Spots, SpotViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpotViewHolder spotViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Spots spots) {
        if(i > 3)
            // Do something with i > 3
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SpotViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_app_spots, parent, false);
        return new SpotViewHolder(view);
    }
};

if(adapter.getItemCount() == 0)
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Override onDataChanged() and check in it

```
FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Spots, SpotViewHolder> adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Spots, SpotViewHolder>(options) {
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SpotViewHolder spotViewHolder, int i, @NonNull Spots spots) {
    //...
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public SpotViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    //...
    }


    // Add this
    @Override
    public void onDataChanged() {
    // do your thing
    if(getItemCount() == 0)
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: "Variable 'adapter' might not have been initialized". I believe you can't put the adapter variable inside it's own function

Comment: It is a warning, you can enclose it with try catch.

Comment: I think it will be hinted by android studio itself otherwise just use generic Exception e syntax

Comment: There is no hint from AS :( also the error didn't go away

Comment: Error or warning?

Comment: Error, the program won't compile

Comment: Try alt+enter on the adapter underlined in red, it will give you some hint

Comment: That's the problem, it doesn't give a solution. It gives "Add braces to 'if' statement", "flip '=='" and two others non-solution possibilities

Comment: Try using just getitemcount

Comment: if(getItemCount() == 0)

Comment: And it cannot be "protected" it must be a public function

Comment: Cool. That was my mistake, getitemcount already exists in the adapter class we just need to use it. Happy to help.